# How to query the custom field using postman query in order. Below example query we tried not working

Tags: postman-collection-runner, commercetools

```
"custom": {
"type": {
"typeId": "type",
"id": "023c76a9-25ce-4937-987c-b1375be9f2bf"
},
"fields": {
"pending": "pending"
}
},
```

We tried below query but not working

```
?where=custom(fields.pending:"pending")
```

We tried this below query to filter data but not working.

```
{{host}}/{{project-key}}/orders?where=custom(fields.pending:"pending")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method by passing where condition through postman
{{host}}/{{project-key}}/orders?where=custom(fields(pending%3D%20"pending"))